# How can I collect dynamic fields data in jQuery and pass it to AJAX and also retrieve it in PHP one by one field?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have tried with the following example, but this is not working. I don't know how to collect each field data in PHP, I searched on many sites and got suggestions that I have to serialize all the field, but still not working.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var id_input=1;
  var max_fields      = 5; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper       = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
  var x = 1; //initlal text box count

    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
               e.preventDefault();
               if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                  x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" id="mytext'+ id_input++ + '" name="mytext[]" /><a href="#" id="rm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign remove"></span></a></div>'); //add input box
                }
  });



$(wrapper).on("click","#rm", function(e){ //remove div
 e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); 
 });
$('#btn').click(function(){
            var str= $('#mytext').serialize();
              $.ajax({
                      type:"POST",
                      url:"demot2.php",
                      data:{str:str},
                      success:function(data){
                            $("#output").html(data);
                      }
              });
</script></head>
<body>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
<button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
<div><input type="text"  id="mytext0" name="mytext[]" /></div>
</div><button type="submit" id="btn">Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `add_button` is not defined anywhere, there should be an error showing up in the console.

Comment: thanks for the reply, now I have added, but still not working

Comment: Okay, but still `$('#mytext')` should be undefined.